# Swift: почему требуется прописать внешнее имя при передаче параметра?

Tags: xcode, swift

Изучаю swift, наткнулся на нестыковки с книгой. Вот этот код не работает:

```
func yu(a : Int, b : Float) -> Int {
    return a+Int(b)
}
print(yu(25, 6));
```

Xcode настойчиво рекомендует `print(yu(25, b: 6));`
На сколько я понял, можно передавать параметры так: `print(yu(25, 6));` Тут написано все:
http://swiftbook.ru/doc/functions/function-parameter-names

Почему он просит `b:`? Когда 1 параметр передаю в `func yu(a : Int);` то все норм, а вот 2 уже какие-то выпендрозы.

Вот тут есть решение: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24050844/swift-missing-argument-label-xxx-in-call  , но оно не работает. У меня нет классов. Мой Swift не поддерживает "#"

Answer (score 1):

В общем, это пошло еще с Objective-c, первый параметр может не иметь внешнего имени, а все последующие обязательно должны, например:

```
- (void)sayMe:(NSString *)text;

- (void)sayMe:(NSString *)text inLanguage:(NSString *)language;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ тут: https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

Functions With Multiple Parameters

Functions can have multiple input parameters, which are written within the function’s parentheses, separated by commas.

This function takes a person’s name and whether they have already been greeted as input, and returns an appropriate greeting for that person:

```
func sayHello(personName: String, alreadyGreeted: Bool) -> String {
    if alreadyGreeted {
        return sayHelloAgain(personName)
    } else {
        return sayHello(personName)
    }
}
print(sayHello("Tim", alreadyGreeted: true))
// Prints "Hello again, Tim!"
```

You call the `sayHello(_:alreadyGreeted:)` function by passing it both a String argument value and a Bool argument value labeled alreadyGreeted in parentheses, separated by commas. Note that this function is distinct from the `sayHello(_:)` function shown in an earlier section. Although both functions have names that begin with sayHello, the `sayHello(_:alreadyGreeted:)` function takes two arguments but the `sayHello(_:)` function takes only one.

When calling a function with more than one parameter, any argument after the first is labeled according to its corresponding parameter name. Function parameter naming is described in more detail in Function Parameter Names.